# How to detect when the destination side rejects the call an application for Android based on Voximplant

Tags: voximplant

I have an application for Android based on Voximplant platform. I need to know when the destination side rejects the call. How do I find that it was the other side who rejected the call?

Answer (score 0):

If the call on Android rejects via the ICall.reject() method, the caller side will receive the OnCallFailed event with the 480 or 603 error code, depending on the RejectMode.